# Facebook Account Kit : NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, facebook, account-kit

I have this error with android studio Facebook Account Kit

```
Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$zzf;
```

Detail Log

> 07-25 16:23:41.683 20088-20088/com.nazir.shopping E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.nazir.shopping, PID: 20088
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$zzf;
>           at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth.(Unknown Source:0)
>           at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity.onCreate(AccountKitActivity.java:281)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7117)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7108)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1262)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:101)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:73)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zzf" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file "/data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/base.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/lib/x86,
>   /data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/base.apk!/lib/x86,
>   /data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/x86,
>   /data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk!/lib/x86,
>   /data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/x86,
>   /data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/x86,
>   /data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/x86,
>   /data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/x86,
>   /data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/x86,
>   /data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/x86,
>   /data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/x86,
>   /data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/x86,
>   /data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/x86,
>   /data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>             ... 17 more
>         Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location
>   /data/app/com.nazir.shopping-VZh5unWKQWN7d8SWHtKjbw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:356)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:103)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:77)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.(DexPathList.java:157)
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
>           at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.(PathClassLoader.java:64)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
>           at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:72)
>           at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:38)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:713)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:747)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:969)
>           at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2298)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5754)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1623)
>                 ... 6 more

Comment: Please share some codes on how you implemented this.

Comment: any luck finding a solution for this?

Answer (score 9):

This is happen when we try to authenticate user with some authenticate service like `AccountKit` `FirebaseAuth` and those service depends on `play-services-auth` So, Add

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'`

add this in dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! Its worked for me. I already added dependancy, but it was of older version.

Answer (score 3):

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.37.0'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:16.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
```

Just update so it works.

Comment: This is correct. You need to explicitly add the play services library